# Clarifying The activeDirection in Graphx pregel api for computing on an undirected graph

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I need to use the Graphx Pregel API to run computations on an undirected graph. would it ignore the directionality of the graph if I set 
activeDirection = EdgeDirection.Either ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like activeDirection is only used to determine whether or not to run "sendMsg" in the next iteration according to [this source](http://note.yuhc.me/2015/03/graphx-pregel-shortest-path/)

Further, [this post](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Graphx-undirected-graph-support-td2142.html#a13028) seems to suggest undirected graphs are not supported.

Finally, my experiments confirm what these guys are saying...

Comment: as a workaround you can use graph.reverse() to add edges in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks ,I later realized that the sendMsg is called for both source and destination when I set EdgeDirection.Either, So I can use that to send a message to the source node from the source node. It works, but it feels harder to reason about. Maybe I just need to spend more time with the pregel interface to start reasoning clearly with it.
Something similar to 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/graphx/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/graphx/lib/ConnectedComponents.scala#L47

Comment: Exactly! Great example to use connected components. Much better than doubling the edges :)